# How to download datasets from web using r?

Tags: r

I want to download datasets from the web that include a raw of data for example  from

```
http://www.ebi.ac.uk/arrayexpress/experiments/browse.html?keywords=&organism=&array=&exptype%5B%5D=&exptype%5B%5D=%22array+assay%22
```

using R code. I want to download as much data as much as possible -- not file by file but all of the data accessible via the above URL.

Answer (score 2):

```
#Right click on webpage-> View page source-> select all text and save as html file, here 'html_rawsrc.html'

require(XML)
doc <- htmlParse("html_rawsrc.html")

#get all links
links <- xpathSApply(doc, "//a/@href")

#subset links containing pattern 'raw.1.zip'
rawdata_links<-links[grep("raw[.]1[.]zip",links)]

#prepare vector of complete url's
rawdata_vec<-do.call(rbind,lapply(links[grep("raw[.]1[.]zip",links)],function(x) { names(x)<-NULL; return(paste0("http://www.ebi.ac.uk",x)) } ))
row.names(rawdata_vec)<-NULL

head(rawdata_vec,2)
#     [,1]                                                                       
#[1,] "http://www.ebi.ac.uk/arrayexpress/files/E-MTAB-2549/E-MTAB-2549.raw.1.zip"
#[2,] "http://www.ebi.ac.uk/arrayexpress/files/E-MTAB-1710/E-MTAB-1710.raw.1.zip"

#prepate vector of file names to be saved
rawdata_filenames<-do.call(rbind,lapply(strsplit(rawdata_vec,split="/"),function(x) x[7]))

head(rawdata_filenames,2)
#     [,1]                   
#[1,] "E-MTAB-2549.raw.1.zip"
#[2,] "E-MTAB-1710.raw.1.zip"

#loop through each file index and download corresponding file
lapply(1:length(rawdata_filenames),function(x)  download.file(rawdata_vec[x],destfile=rawdata_filenames[x]) )

#trying URL 'http://www.ebi.ac.uk/arrayexpress/files/E-MTAB-2549/E-MTAB-2549.raw.1.zip'
#Content type 'application/zip' length 34494471 bytes (32.9 Mb)
#opened URL
#downloaded 32.9 Mb
```

Comment: I want to download all datasets that appears under the raw :
URL http://www.ebi.ac.uk/arrayexpress/experiments/browse.html?keywords=&organism=Homo+sapiens&array=&exptype%5B%5D=&exptype%5B%5D=%22array+assay%22
 
So it is for 15671 pages each page have column(Raw), my question is .How to download all data files under the Raw as shown in the above figure for 15671 pages > (all datasets) in this URL (http://www.ebi.ac.uk/arrayexpress/experiments/browse.html?keywords=&organism=Homo+sapiens&array=&exptype%5B%5D=&exptype%5B%5D=%22array+assay%22)

Comment: OK, I have solved the problem here for page 1 of 15671 pages. 1) What changes can you observe in the url (address bar) when you click on page 2 of results 2) What would be the edit required in the url of step 1 3) How can you make use of my solution after step 1 and 2 , you need to tell us your experience from the above

Comment: I think just the page number is changed only from page no 1 to 15671.but where is your solution, do you solve the problem using r code? if yeas write the code if possible.

Comment: [page 2 of results ](http://www.ebi.ac.uk/arrayexpress/experiments/browse.html?keywords=&organism=Homo+sapiens&array=&exptype%5B%5D=&exptype%5B%5D=%22array+assay%22&page=2&pagesize=25), hint: you have to change pagesize=15671, right click , select all text save as html file and use my code from above

Comment: in short: remove '&page=2' and change 'pagesize=15678'

Comment: OK,  I saved it all text as html (file name = html_rawsrc.html)

Comment: I install (XML) package, could we start step by step

Comment: Could you explain this steps doc <- htmlParse("html_rawsrc.html")

#get all links
links <- xpathSApply(doc, "//a/@href")

#subset links containing pattern 'raw.1.zip'
rawdata_links<-links[grep("raw[.]1[.]zip",links)]

Comment: unfortunately this cannot be moved to chat. Copy the html file to the path obtained from running `getwd()`. Select all of the code and run it, let us know whether the download works. I will explain the steps when its working for you

Comment: you mean the file (html or URL OF THIS FILE

Comment: You mean (getwd(file:///H:/Desktop/hml.htm) this the path and then I have past the above code togather and run it?  or....?

Comment: in your R session, type `getwd()`, see the output of this command and copy the html file you saved earlier to this new path

Comment: it successful, but it work just for few mints I mean just for 12  files and saved in directory. this is the error massage as shown below  Warning message:
In download.file(rawdata_vec[x], destfile = rawdata_filenames[x]) :
  downloaded length 13819904 != reported length 15544467
> 
> #trying URL 'http://www.ebi.ac.uk/arrayexpress/files/E-MTAB-2549/E-MTAB-2549.raw.1.zip'
> #Content type 'application/zip' length 34494471 bytes (32.9 Mb)

Comment: ok good its working for you, can you post here the output of `length(rawdata_filenames)`, this is the number of raw data file links  present in the html file

Comment: The  length(rawdata_filenames) =
[1] 14

Comment: you have not saved the html file properly hence the low count of files, (view-source:http://www.ebi.ac.uk/arrayexpress/experiments/browse.html?keywords=&organism=Homo+sapiens&array=&exptype%5B%5D=&exptype%5B%5D=%22array+assay%22&page=1&pagesize=5000) paste this link in chrome and save html file, this has 5000 experiments, once you save the first html file, change `&page=2` in this url, you will have next 5000 experiments, save this as a different html file and so on for all four pages. With all 4 html files, run my code for each html file by changing this `doc<-htmlParse("html_rawsrc.html")`

Comment: This is the link that I used  (view-source:http://www.ebi.ac.uk/arrayexpress/experiments/browse.html?keywords=&organism=Homo+sapiens&array=&exptype%5B%5D=&exptype%5B%5D=&page=1&pagesize=18163), and this is theilnk for 5000 what is the differenc in size (view-source:http://www.ebi.ac.uk/arrayexpress/experiments/browse.html?keywords=&organism=Homo+sapiens&array=&exptype%5B%5D=&exptype%5B%5D=%22array+assay%22&page=2&pagesize=5000)

Comment: in your link you have `page=1` and this will not work for `pagesize=18163` as the html file will be very large in size and you will be unable to save it, try the approach I mentioned earlier

Comment: Ok, I it is work but the I will run it because I think it needs big hard disk size, but the problem with the data that I downloaded, it is mixed between text in the binging of file and you know that the R just  deal with the columns, is there code to remove the rows which include information about the samples, I mean the file should be consist of just columns

Comment: for example you can just download one file, in order to understand my point of view. from the web by one click on the data file

Comment: if the data download has worked according to your requirements then you can accept this answer to close this request. Regarding your other issues, you have create a new question with posting the R code **YOU** have tried and has not worked for you